# How to only apply <li> css to footer and nothing else?

Tags: html, css

In my CSS, I have my `li` set `display: inline;`. I understand that anything between `<li>` and `</li>` will display inline. However, I want some list elements that are not inline. I've tried creating a `<div>` around my footer and writing `display: inline;` there but bullet points appear. How can I keep my footer inline but have freedom over what I want the rest of my `li` elements to be?

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
   <p>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="etc.html>Etc</a></li>
   </ul>
   </p>
</div>
```

...

```
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
<ol>
     <li> consectetur adipiscing elit </li>
     <li> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
display: inline;
font-size: 1em;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

I want to create a list that isn't inline. I tried moving the `display: inline;` portion to `#footer` but had bullet points in the footer. How can I keep the footer's formatting yet still create non-inline lists?

Comment: Not understand what you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a CSS selector with a *Descendant Combinator*, represented by a whitespace .  If you have your selector as `A B`, the styles inside the brackets will be applied to all `B` elements that are inside an `A` element.

For you, you could have the CSS as the following:

```
#footer li {
display: inline;
font-size: 1em;
margin-right: 10px
}

#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center
}
```

What this does is it applies the style to any `li` elements inside an element with the id `#footer`.

---

More on [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

More on [descendant combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

Comment: Wow, that was an incredibly simple and insightful tip. I appreciate that you figured out what I was asking about. Thank you very much for the help!